# Iterate through an array and back once it reaches the end

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

## What I want

I am trying to iterate through an array from the start (logging all the elements) then once the end is reached, go back through the array. Once it has reached the start again, it will go through the array again. It will do this forever.

Example:

> Array  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>
> Log: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3...

---

## What I have tried

This is what I have tried:

```
let a = 0;
let dir = -1;
let arr = new Array();

function setup() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
  }
}

function draw() {
  for (let el of arr) {
    console.log(el);
  }

  if (i >= arr.length || i <= 0) {
    dir *= -1;
  }

  i += dir;
}
```

If you are unaware, this is a p5.js sketch. The `setup()` function runs on the page load and the `draw()` function runs repetitively.

---

## What happened

[This is what happened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lghBo.png)

Comment: well your problem is exactly what it says: you never defined `i`. Also your code doesn't even log the element.

Comment: I can't think of a single use case of this. I really wonder what you're trying to do.

Comment: And the browser would lock up

Comment: @SourceOverflow Thank you, didn't realise this

Comment: @OverCoder I do have a use for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stop_count` is for testing only, preventing it loops forever.

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
let dir = 1;
let stop_count = 0;

while (stop_count <10) {
    let i;
    i = dir===1 ? 0 : arr.length-1;
    console.log(arr[i]);
    i+=dir;
    while (i < arr.length-1 && i >=1){
        console.log(arr[i]);
        i+=dir;
    }
    dir = dir*-1;
    stop_count += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array functions such as `concat`, `map`, `slice`,`reverse` and `forEach` or `map` instead of looping:

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

var upDown = arr.concat(
  //not the last one or 5 will be logged twice
  arr.slice(0,-1)
  //reverse order
  .reverse()
);
upDown.forEach(
  item=>console.log(item)
);
```

Your draw function can look like this:

```
var draw =(function(){
  var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
  var upDown = arr.concat(
    arr.slice(0,-1)
    .reverse()
  );
  var index = -1;
  return function(){
    index = (index===upDown.length-1)
      ? 0
      : index+1;
    console.log(upDown[index]);
  }
}());//IIFE to set up upDown array and index
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the **modulo** (`%`) operator to get the element index:

```js
0 % 10 === 0
1 % 10 === 1
2 % 10 === 2
// ...
8 % 10 === 8
9 % 10 === 9
10 % 10 === 0
11 % 10 === 1
12 % 10 === 2
// ...
```